# django rest framework 3.1 Handle create/update in ModelSerializer where do i validate the nested data?

Tags: django-rest-framework

I try to create and update resources using a nested representation.

I took a look here -> http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#writable-nested-representations. But i don't know where to put the validation to verify that my nested resources, which is not defined by its id, exists.

## json

```
{
    "name": "this is my name"
    "network": {
        "code": "existing_code",
        "operator": "existing_op"
    },
 }
```

## create method of my serializer

```
def create(self, validated_data):

    network = validated_data.pop("network")

    #this could throw a DoesNotExist exception !!!!
    validated_data["network"] = Network.objects.get(operator=network["operator"], code=network["code"])

    instance = manny.common.models.DeliveryPoint.objects.create(**validated_data)
    return instance
```

Is it okay to check this in the validator directly on the ModelSerializer:

## validate method of my serializer

```
def validate(self, data):
    #some code here....

    if not Network.objects.filter(operator=data["operator"], code=data["code"]).exists():
        raise serializers.ValidationError("network doesn't exist")
    return data
```

Or do i have to rewrite the create method of the ModelViewSet ?

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use a `get_object_or_404` (https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/1.8/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404) instead of `Network.objects.get` ?

If the Network object doesn't exist, the raised exception will make a 404 error, and you won't need to handle it manually.

Comment: Hi, I thought that a Http404 Exception thrown in the serializer wouldn't be correctly handled by the view but... i was wrong, thanks for your response !